# grunt-sftp-deploy unable to connect to server

Tags: powershell, gruntjs, sftp

I am a noob to grunt and would like to start using it. 
Here is my gruntfile:

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {

// Project configuration.
grunt.initConfig({
pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),
devDir: 'dev/dir',
prodDir: 'prod/dir',

'sftp-deploy': {
  prod: {
    auth: {
      host: 'server.com',
      port: 22,
      authKey: {
        "username": "username1",
        "password": "password2"
      }
    },
    src: '<%=devDir%>',
    dest: '/test/env/',
    concurrency: 4,
    progress: true
  }
}
});

// load modules
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-sftp-deploy');
// Default task(s).
grunt.registerTask('default', ['sftp-deploy']);

};
```

I am getting this error when i run 'grunt' in powershell:

Running "sftp-deploy:prod" (sftp-deploy) task

Logging in with username username1

Concurrency : 4

Fatal error: Connection :: error

What am I doing wrong?
thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, a few things to try...  (sorry - a month late!)

run:

```
 grunt sftp-deploy --verbose
```

This will give you a little more info regarding your error.

I solved my error after realising I couldn't create folders on my server, only upload files. So it might be worth testing that you can accomplish manually what your asking grunt to do.

Lastly, try moving your username / password into a .ftppass file

link [here] (https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-sftp-deploy)